# Using LinqToXSD, how to get the objects in a xml without casting?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml, linq-to-xsd

I'm using this technology to manage my XML files as Databases. When I do this, normally I created the classes in a library and using XSD.exe I can get my XSD.

Then, with LinqToXSD and my new XSD generated, I can access to the data. This is my first class which should be in my program.

```
public class Foo
{
    string FirstName
    string LastName
}
```

And to access the data I used this namespace

```
urn.foo
```

And I realized, that they are two different classes, I mean I need to convert this class (urn.foo from XSD) into real Foo (the first one). So, I have two different classes, and I want to have just one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xsd.exe generates `partial` classes. So, if you put your “real” `Foo` into the same namespace in the same assembly as the generated one, make it `partial` too and remove any duplicated parts, then you will have only one `Foo` type.